# RTK Query. Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I've a component LoginForm, where user can open login form and enter date for enter the site or registration on it.
I use RTK query and React hook form for it.

In this component we are interested registerUser and loginIn, others I've deleted

```
export const requestApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'requestApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/',
      prepareHeaders: (headers:any) => {
    headers.set('authorization', localStorage.getItem('token'));
         return headers;
       },
    }),
    tagTypes: ['request'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      registerUser: builder.mutation<any, any>({
         query: (params) => ({
              url: '/auth/registration',
              method: 'POST',
              body: params,
          }),
      }),
      loginIn: builder.query<any, any>({
              query: (params) => ({
               url: '/auth/login',
               method: 'POST',
               body: params,
              }),
          }),
      }),
});
    
export const {
    useGetSortedFilmQuery,
    useRegisterUserMutation,
    useLoginInQuery,
    useGetInfoUserQuery,
    useAddFilmQuery,
} = requestApi;
```

Go next.
Here is the component LoginForm. I've deleted from the component, all of we don't need.
In this component I've function registerIn and I can use it. This function is in hook useRegisterUserMutation.
But in other hook useLoginInQuery, I don't have such function and I must use hook in the body component, but I want to use in the function inside.
Let's look the component.
How correctly to send the request for loginIn, if I use RTK query and I must use hook at the top of the component.
When I use hook useLoginInQuery in the body of the component, it's not well, becourse request sends every time when I open form(I've written nothing). Maybe I've done somethink wrong ?

```
export const LoginForm:FC<LoginFormProps> = (props) => {

        // here I've function registerIn
    const [registerIn, {
    data: requestRegister, error: errorRegister, isError: isErrorRegister, isLoading: loadingRegister,
    }] = useRegisterUserMutation();

        // here I don't have function
    const {data: userLogin, isError: isErrorLogin, isLoading: loadLogin, error: errorLogin,} = useLoginInQuery({ phoneNumber: element.mailOrNumberLoginIn, password: element.passwordLogin });

        // React hook form
    const {register, handleSubmit, setError, formState: { errors, isValid },} = useForm<loginForm>({mode: 'onChange',});

        // Here it's working well
const sendRegisterForm = (element:any) => {
    if (Number.isFinite(+element.mailOrNumberRegistration.replace('+', ''))) { registerIn({ phoneNumber: element.mailOrNumberRegistration, password: element.passwordRegistration });
    } else { registerIn({ email: element.mailOrNumberRegistration, password: element.passwordRegistration });}};

        // But here I see problem: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. 
const sendLoginForm = (element:any) => {
    if (Number.isFinite(+element.mailOrNumberLoginIn.replace('+', ''))) {
    const {data: userLogin, isError: isErrorLogin, isLoading: loadLogin, error: errorLogin,} = useLoginInQuery({ phoneNumber: element.mailOrNumberLoginIn, password: element.passwordLogin });
    console.log(userLogin);} else {
    const {data: userLogin, isError: isErrorLogin, isLoading: loadLogin, error: errorLogin,} = useLoginInQuery({ email: element.mailOrNumberLoginIn, password: element.passwordLogin });
    console.log(userLogin);}};

    //when I send form
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<loginForm> = (data) => {
    // console.log(data);
    if (clickOnEnter === 0) {
       sendLoginForm(data);
    }
    if (clickOnEnter === 1) {
       sendRegisterForm(data);
    // if (requestRegister && requestRegister.message === 'Учетная запись создана') {
    //     dispatch(changeStateClickOnEnter(3));
    // }
    }
};
    
      
    return (
    <div className={classNames(cls.LoginForm, {}, [classname])}>
         { clickOnEnter === 0
             && (
    <form
         className={cls.form}
         onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
         onChange={checkTextFormsLogin}
    >
    <h2
         className={cls.title}
    >
         {t('Вход в учетную запись')}
    </h2>
    <div className={cls.inputsForm}>
    <Input
         type={loginsText.loginWindow}
         classForInput={cls.input}
         placeholder="Логин или номер телефона"
         autofocus
         defaultValue={textFromForms.loginIn}
         autoComplete="login"
         forRef={loginRef}  
         register{{...register('mailOrNumberLoginIn') }}
    />
    <Input
         classForInput={cls.input}
         type={passwordHideButton.loginShowHide ? 'text' : 'password'}
         placeholder="Пароль"
         defaultValue={textFromForms.passwordLogin}
         autoComplete="password"
         forRef={passwordLoginRef}
         register={{ ...register('passwordLoginIn') }}
    >
    {
         passwordHideButton.login
    && (
         <Button
         type="button"
         className={cls.hideButton}
         onClick={showAndHideTextLoginInPassword}
    >
                                               
    {!passwordHideButton.loginShowHide ? <ShowSvg className={cls.showSvg} /> : <HideSvg className={cls.hideSvg} />}
    </Button>)}
    </Input>
    </div>
          <div className={cls.btnCover}>
          <div className={cls.blockAdditional}>
               <Button
                   className={cls.profileRegistration}
                   onClick={changeStateEnterOrRegister}
               >
                   { t('Нет учетной записи')}
               </Button>
               <Button
                   className={cls.forgetPassword}
                   onClick={openWindowRecoveryAccess}
               >
                   { t('Забыли логин или пароль')}
                </Button>
           </div>
           <div className={cls.button}>
                <Button
                   className={cls.btnEnter}
                   type="submit"
                >
                    { t('Войти')}
                </Button>
          </div>
           </div>
                        </form>
                    )}
                { clickOnEnter === 1
           && (
    <form
        className={cls.form}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        onChange={checkTextFormsRegistration}
    >
    <h2
        className={cls.title}
    >
        {t('Регистрация')}
    </h2>
    <div className={cls.inputsForm}>
    <Input
         type="text"
         classForInput={cls.input}
         placeholder="Логин или номер телефона"
         autofocus
         defaultValue={textFromForms.loginRegister}
         disabled={loadingRegister && true}
         forRef={loginRegisterRef}
    />
    <Input
         classForInput={cls.input}
         type={passwordHideButton.registerShowHide ? 'text' : 'password'}
         placeholder="Пароль"
         defaultValue={textFromForms.passwordRegister}
         disabled={loadingRegister && true}
         forRef={passwordRegisterRef}
         register={{ ...register('passwordRegistration') }}
         onInput={addTextFromRegistrationForm}
    >
    {passwordHideButton.register && (
    <Button
         type="button"
         className={cls.hideButton}
         onClick={showAndHideTextRegistrationPassword}
    >
                                           {!passwordHideButton.registerShowHide ? <ShowSvg className={cls.showSvg} /> : <HideSvg className={cls.hideSvg} />}
       </Button>)}
      </Input>
    </div>
    <div className={cls.btnCoverTwo}>
      <Button
         className={cls.btnEnter}
         onClick={backToLoginIn}
         type="button"
      >
         { t('Вернуться')}
      </Button>
      <Button
         className={cls.btnEnter}
         type="submit"
      >
         { t('Создать учетную запись')}
      </Button>
    </div>
    </form>
    )}
    </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Your `logIn` should be a mutation not a query, exactly the same way you did with `registerUser`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use login as a mutation as well similary as you are doing the register mutation and you can call its method in sendLoginForm

```
loginIn: builder.mutation<any, any>({
            query: (params) => ({
                url: '/auth/login',
                method: 'POST',
                body: params,
            }),
        }),
.....
export const {
    useGetSortedFilmQuery,
    useRegisterUserMutation,
    useLoginInMutation,
    useGetInfoUserQuery,
    useAddFilmQuery,
} = requestApi;
```

And in the LoginForm
you can use it like this

```
  const [login, {
            data: loginData, error: errorLogin, isError: isErrorLogin, isLoading: loadingLogin,
        }] = useLoginInMutation();
```

And in the sendLoginForm function you can call the method login

```
 const sendLoginForm = (element:any) => {
        if (Number.isFinite(+element.mailOrNumberLoginIn.replace('+', ''))) {
            login({ phoneNumber: element.mailOrNumberLoginIn, password: element.passwordLogin });
        } else {
            login({ email: element.mailOrNumberLoginIn, password: element.passwordLogin });
        }
    };
```

Comment: oy yea...It's working. I thougth that I need to use query instead of mutaion.